# CSS positioning images in the correct place

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```css
#cake1 {
  float: left;
}

#cake2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<img id="cake1" src="https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/sites/default/files/styles/category_retina/public/recipe-collections/collection-image/2013/05/rosewater-raspberry-sponge-cake.jpg?itok=OVpUSQm9" />

<h2>Cake</h2>

<img id="cake2" src="https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/sites/default/files/styles/category_retina/public/chocolate-avocado-cake.jpg?itok=E2eWE_Dx" />
```

I am trying to get cake2 to appear under cake1 using CSS, instead of displaying on the right of the image.

Comment: Remove the float.

Comment: Where should the word "Cake" appear?

Answer (score 1):

I just removed `float:left`;

```html
<html>


<head>

 <style>
 
 
 #cake2{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  
 }
 
 </style>

</head>

<body>

 <img id="cake1" src="https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/sites/default/files/styles/category_retina/public/recipe-collections/collection-image/2013/05/rosewater-raspberry-sponge-cake.jpg?itok=OVpUSQm9" />

 
 <h2>Cake</h2>
 
 <img id="cake2" src="https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/sites/default/files/styles/category_retina/public/chocolate-avocado-cake.jpg?itok=E2eWE_Dx" />
 

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the word "Cake" to the right of the first image, and have the second image below them, try clearing the float on the first image and then also floating the second:

```css
#cake1 {
  float: left;
}

#cake2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  clear:left;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<img id="cake1" src="https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/sites/default/files/styles/category_retina/public/recipe-collections/collection-image/2013/05/rosewater-raspberry-sponge-cake.jpg?itok=OVpUSQm9" />

<h2>Cake</h2>

<img id="cake2" src="https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/sites/default/files/styles/category_retina/public/chocolate-avocado-cake.jpg?itok=E2eWE_Dx" />
```

Comment: Yes thanks this seems to work. So the clear: left code ignores all other float styling?

Comment: Clearing the floated image means that the element being cleared (the second image) can't sit next to the floated one and forces it under it. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear